# Validación de número entero con java dentro de este ejercicio

Tags: java

En este ejercicio en Java se solicita que un programa que valide si un número es entero y se da la opción de convertirlo a entero en caso de no serlo.

Se ha intentado realizar la tarea sin éxito con el código a continuación:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ejercicio_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float num;
        String digito;
        int longitud,nuevo_num;
        char ch;

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Ingresa un número: ");
        num = stdIn.nextFloat();
        digito = Float.toString(num);
        longitud = digito.length();

        for(int i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
            if(digito.charAt(i) == '.') {
                num=Float.parseFloat(digito);
                System.out.printf("El número %.0f no es correcto", num);
                System.out.println("\n Desea convertir su número a entero (S/N)?: ");
                ch = stdIn.nextLine().charAt(0);
                if (ch == 'S'|| ch == 'N') {
                    nuevo_num = (int) num;
                    System.out.printf("El número %f, ahora es %d.", num,nuevo_num);
                }
                else {
                    num = Float.parseFloat(digito);
                    System.out.printf("El número %.0f es correcto", num);
                }
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo exactamente lo que quieres conseguir...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que `Scanner.nextFloat()` no toma en cuenta el caracter de salto de línea \n, por lo que este es leido por la siguiente llamada a `Scanner.nextLine()`, que devuelve un string vacío. Esto arroja *java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0* cuando intentas acceder al primer caracter leido con `ch = stdIn.nextLine().charAt(0)`

Solo debes agregar una nueva llamada a `Scanner.nextLine()` despues de leer el número ingresado. Aquí dejo tu código con esa pequeña correción:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    float num;
    String digito;
    int longitud,nuevo_num;
    char ch;

    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Ingresa un número: ");
    num = stdIn.nextFloat();

    stdIn.nextLine();

    digito = Float.toString(num);
    longitud = digito.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
        if(digito.charAt(i) == '.') {
            num=Float.parseFloat(digito);
            System.out.printf("El número %.0f no es correcto", num);
            System.out.println("\n Desea convertir su número a entero (S/N)?: ");
            ch = stdIn.nextLine().charAt(0);
            if (ch == 'S'|| ch == 'N') {
                nuevo_num = (int) num;
                System.out.printf("El número %f, ahora es %d.", num,nuevo_num);
            }
            else {
                num = Float.parseFloat(digito);
                System.out.printf("El número %.0f es correcto", num);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado. ¡Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias. Que respuesta tan eficiente.